# How to join 2 tables with many to many relationship without the same number or rows

Tags: mysql, join

I want to join 2 tables with many to many relationships.

I already tried the Left, Right and other Joining of table methods but I can't get my expected result.

This is a sample:

**tblcharge**

[image]

**tblgrades**

[image]

This is my code

```
SELECT a.student_id,
a.description,
b.subject_id FROM tblcharge AS a 
LEFT JOIN  tblgrades AS b ON 
(a.student_id=b.student_id) AND b.school_yr_id=18 AND b.semester_id=1 
WHERE a.sy_id=18 AND a.sem_id=1 AND a.student_id='15-3060'
```

Output

[image]

What i want is like this

[image]

Comment: Please explain the logic between the two tables.

Comment: I already updated my question sir.

Comment: Tried cross apply? My phone is not loading the images so I can't tell if it's what you are looking for

Comment: I'll check it if that might solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a `left join` to me:

```
select t1.id, t1.item, t2.item
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id and t1.item = t2.item;
```

Comment: But the items in the table 2 is not the same in Table 1

Comment: @Nexus . . . They are for id = 101.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT grd.STUDENT_ID,chrg.DESCRIPTION, grd.SUBJECT_ID 
FROM TBLGRADES grd CROSS JOIN TBLCHARGE chrg 
WHERE grd.STUDENT_ID = chrg.STUDENT_ID
```

Comment: I tried to use your script but it does not fix the problem. :( It returns the same number of rows in the OUPUT image above. The difference is the rows in tblcharge displays according to order but the SUBJECTID loops in each row in the tblcharge.

Comment: Can i chat without you so i can show to you the result?

Comment: try using the other joins, then place grd.STUDENT_ID = chrg.STUDENT_ID in ON clause, even a simple join in your problem will do

Comment: also try moving this code of yours (AND b.school_yr_id=18 AND b.semester_id=1) to where clause.

Comment: I already try other joins and placed (AND b.school_yr_id=18 AND b.semester_id=1) to where clause but it shows the same result.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.